# Hugging Face Model import error to Jupyter Notebook :

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, huggingface-transformers

When I try to import a pre-trained fine tuned model from hugging face to jupyter notebook it's shows that the Kernel Restarting: The kernel for .ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

```
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model="lvkaokao/mistral-7b-finetuned-orca-dpo-v2")

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM 

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("lvkaokao/mistral-7b-finetuned-orca-dpo-v2")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("lvkaokao/mistral-7b-finetuned-orca-dpo-v2")
```

This is the process by which I try to import the model in jupyter notebook!

How to solve this and how can I import the model properly?

Comment: I think you're running out of RAM. Please check your RAM usage when you're executing the cell.